# matching results with sklearn average_precision_score

Tags: python, classification, scikit-learn, implementation

I have written a (convenience) class for binary classification in python which takes several models and compares their ROCs, AvPrecisions, and creates several charts (distribution of scores, accuracy/sensitivity/specificity, ROC, PR, etc.).

A key difference that I am observing is in the computation of average precision.  For some examples, using `average_precision_score(true labels, prob score)` I get a value which is 0.1% to 0.2% more than the average precision computed as

```
xaxs,yaxs = df['sens'].values[::-1],df['ppv'].values[::-1]
ap = yaxs[:-1]*(xaxs[1:]-xaxs[:-1])
```

or equivalently

```
xaxs,yaxs = df['sens'].values,df['ppv'].values
tmp = yaxs[1:]*(xaxs[:-1]-xaxs[1:])
```

I do the same for AUC and that matches to second place of decimal.  Based on the formula given [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score.html) the above calculation seems to be correct.

In the figure shown, the values computed by `scikit-learn` are 0.8977 and 0.8722.  Whereas the values compute by the numpy code above are 0.895 and 0.8697.  I am using 10,001 thresholds between 0 and 1 so I would think that the bumps in the left corner of the chart should be adequately captured.

I would welcome input on how to change my calculation to match the one from skl. Thx.

[image: precision recall curve]